# Print apostrophe in python string

Tags: python, django, string

I've this view in my view

```
def terms(request):
    d = getVariables(request,dictionary={'page_name': "Jack's Terms of Service"})  
    return render(request, 'jack/terms.html', d)
```

I'm rendering this as a page title in the templates

```
<title>{{ page_name }}</title>
```

But for some reason it prints the page_ name like this

```
<title>Jack&#39;s Terms of Service</title>
```

I don't know why it's not printing the apostrophe in the string.

Comment: Try this: <title>{{ page_name|safe }}</title>

Comment: Awesome it works! You can put your comment as an answer and I can mark as a tick. Could also explain what this |safe thing is doing to make it work?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **safe**. It marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output.

```
<title>{{ page_name|safe }}</title>
```

Documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe